# File Copy - Keep both files if name conflicts

Tags: c#, .net

File.Copy allows simple file copying.   When a duplicate file name is encountered, File.Copy has a third parameter to determine if the original file is overwritten or not.

Is there a built-in .Net function that allows a third option to rename the copied file and hence keep both files?.   For example, the file copy would automatically rename "readme.txt" to "readme - Copy.txt" if another readme.txt already existed in the destination folder - similar to Windows Explorer functionality?

I realize it can be written but didn't want reinvent the wheel if it exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how do you think there is a third option if that parameter is a `bool`? I think you have to write that functionality your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do all-in-one go with `File.Copy`, however you could test if the destination exists and then `Move` instead.
`Move` takes two parameters, and you can essentially rename at the same time.

```
if File.Exists(destinationPath) {
    File.Move(source, destinationPathRenamed);
} else {
    try {
        File.Copy(source, destinationPath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // destinationPath file already exists
        File.Move(source, destinationPathRenamed);
    }
}
```

See [Move documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Updated code above. @xanatos makes a good point about atomic operation. I made no assumptions about whether there are other processes accessing the file(s).

Note that I haven't added other error handling for the source file being deleted before the operation begins either.

Comment: This isn't "atomic". The file could "appear" after the Exists and before the Copy.

Comment: @xanatos makes a good point. Improved my answer a little. To really make it watertight it needs a lot of checking and error handling. The core of the answer will get lost in all the testing and exception handling code.

Comment: @Neil this one you mean? :-) http://ideone.com/c00hh It has already accepted the anwer, so you are free to add it to your solution if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this functionality doesn't exist out of the box (thankfully, as it would introduce a responsibility to the framework which it ought not to have*,) so if you want this, then you will need to implement a bespoke solution.

*<sub>Which implementation *should* it take? Appending "- Copy", appending "(*n*)"? It becomes problematic rather sherpish.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
var destinationPath = c:\temp\archive.txt;
 if(File.Exists(destinationPath))
     destinationPath = string.Format("c:\temp\archive.{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmffff"));
```

File.Move(filePath, destinationPath );